# Design tab shows only ruler and cross in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I imported a project and every design XML file shows the same thing.
Also I can't drag anything onto the area.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The drop down for API version shows 'null'. Do you have the appropriate SDK platform packages installed? Also, does this project build without errors?